# How to running Matrix based on Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, matrix

I was running the MapReduce Matrix Multiplication.java program found at http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html.

**First:**
$javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d Matrix MatrixMultiply.java

$jar -cvf Matrix.jar -C Matrix .

**Second:**
$/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -put MatrixA MA
$/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -put MatrixB MB

/MA/A.txt
0 0 0
0 1 6
7 8 9
/MB/B.txt
6 7 4
9 1 3
7 6 2

**Finally:**
$/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar MatrixMultiply.jar org/apache/hadoop/examples/MatrixMultiply /MA /MB /output /tempDirPath 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3

But can't working, what I missed detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

[Matrix Multiplication](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/matrix-multiplication-in-hadoop.html)

There is a little difference in input file.
Your input file should contain both the matrix labeled with matrix name,row,col and the element.

Comment: https://github.com/studhadoop/Matrix-Multiplication/blob/master/README.md Please let me know if you have furthr doubts.